# Associated sequence of differences to a sequence: show that $\{a_{n}\}=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ has a limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

An excercise from the infinite sequences chapter i am reading is: show that $a_{1}= \sqrt{2}, a_{2}= \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2}}, \cdots, a_{n} = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ is bounded above by 3.

In the series chapter it says

i: Test for Divergence; if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} \neq 0$ the series diverges.

ii: Necessary condition for convergence; if $\sum a_{n}$ converges then $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$.

I think I use the sequence of partial differences or use the limit of the sequence of differences to show that is bounded; how do I finish the exercise?

Comment: Hi :) Use induction to show that it is bounded by 3. First, prove: If $x<3$, then $\sqrt{2+x}<3$, too. Your statement is false. If $a_n\to 0$, then the series $\sum a_n$ can still diverge. The converse is true. If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to 0$

Comment: I checked the textbook, i am editing that part now i confused it with a box that says "necessary condition for convergence."

Comment: Your exercise is not about series. It's about sequences. And this sequence converges. But you can't show, that $(a_n) _n$ converges by proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}d_n=0$ with $d_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$ because it is a necessary and not sufficient condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ -2 < x < 2,\ $ then $\ 0 < \sqrt{2 + x} < \sqrt{ 2 + 2 } = 2.$

Since $ -2 < a_1 < 2,\ $ and $\ a_{n} = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\ ,\ $ it follows that $\ 0 < a_n < 2\quad \forall\ n\geq 2.$

Since there is no $\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ a_N > 2,\ $ it follows that the sequence $\ (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ is bounded above by $\ 2,\ $ and therefore the sequence is bounded above by $\ 3\ $ also.

Comment: the square of the a1 term was equal to the next term. thanks.

Comment: @opmgal I don't understand what you mean by that.